# IBM Presence Insight RpiProx

Tags: ibm-cloud, raspberry-pi2, presenceinsights

i've been struggling lately with integrating **Rasperry Pi** and **IBM Presence Insight**
for **wifi proximity** detection

the official documentation describes raspberry pi as possible Wifi Proximity sensor, but there is no available documentation

someone tried it before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Raspberry Pi as a proximity sensor, you will need to:

1. Build a raspberry pi device with two different wifi adapters
2. Configure one wifi adapter to be an publicly visible endpoint
3. Write code to capture every time a mobile device tries to connect to the endpoint
4. Report that information back to Presence Insights.

Unfortunately, the chunk of code you need to write has not been open sourced, so you will need to do this on your own.

You could probably hack together a solution. It looks like there are a lot of resources out there online about "seeing who connects to my network [1], [2]" You could probably use one of these solutions and just feed the data into Presence Insights in the correct format (see the documentation about "proximity connectors.")

[1] http://www.howtogeek.com/204057/how-to-see-who%E2%80%99s-connected-to-your-wi-fi-network/

[2] https://github.com/tlhunter/node-wireless